# AVplayer and video files extentions - export and share pipeline

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, avplayer

I would like play a video exported on an S3 server. But I have a doubt on the native video format of Iphone.

I actually fetch the recorded video asset url from the iphone documents, and upload it on s3 adding an .MP4 extension, assuming that this is the original format.

The problem is when I try to read the file from its uploaded url, it doesn't work. Should I convert the file before exporting it ? Did I do any mistake on the extension when I saved it to s3 ? - Weird thing is the file plays in Chrome when I manually open it.
If anybody has a hint .. :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is no need so far to recompress the video, the mp4 extension applies to the original videofile fetched from the camera roll